# How do you replace old knob tube wire in switch box notched in trimmer studs next to front door

Tags: electrical

The three wide light switch box next to our front door was notched in the jack studs around the front door.  I want to replace the knob and tube wiring to this switch, 3 lights and power.  The problem is the old wires run through the studs length wise from above.  There is no good access to these wires from pulling them out and running new wires where they were.  There is access from below but would require drilling up through the studs lengthwise.  Is this even possible?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you run the new wires between the existing studs?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. I'm having a bit of an issue visualizing your problem, [edit]ing your post to include some pictures might help. In general, though, if you can't pull through the same path the old wiring used, you'll have to drill new holes, which may well be easier. Once you've added a couple of pics, take the [tour] to get a feel for the place (and badges redeemable for unicorns and rainbows!) while you're waiting for an answer.

Comment: Art the wires actually sandwiched? That would have been a code violation for k&t but if the wire was braided cloth I have seen that. 
Sometimes cutting a small access panel In The wall and drilling the bottom plate Pulling the wire up is easier in the long run. I would not try and drill up through the stud.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there is a window next to the switches too so no access from the wall. I am trying to pull through old wire holes.  Not successful yet.